# How to I make my bot message the response to a command in a specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

so I've programmed this command that works just fine however my issue is that I cant seem to figure out how to make my bot send the response to the command in a specific channel which I provided the id to:

const allowed_channel_id = guild.channels.cache.get("920766195878228028")

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
    const { TextChannel } = require ('discord.js');
    
    module.exports = {
        commands: ['serverinfo'],
        expectedArgs: '',
        permissionError: 'You need admin permissions to run this command',
        minArgs: 0,
        maxArgs: 0,
        callback: (message, arguments, text) => {
        const server_rules_id = '753465151105138858'
        const server_support_id = '812811612830302219'
        const { guild } = message
        const { name, memberCount, afkTimeout } = guild
        const icon = guild.iconURL()
        const allowed_channel_id = guild.channels.cache.get("920766195878228028")
        let afkTimeout_mins = afkTimeout / 60
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('DARK_PURPLE')
        .setTitle(`Server info for "${name}"`)
        .setDescription("here's all the server information you need to get you started!")
        .setThumbnail(icon)
        .addFields(
          {
            name: 'Make sure to review our rules:',
            value: `<#${server_rules_id}>`,
          },
          {
            name: 'Owners',
            value: `Lexa & FiatLux`,
          },
          {
            name: 'Support channel:',
            value: `<#${server_support_id}>`,
          },
          {
            name: 'Members',
            value: `${memberCount}`,
          },
          {
            name: 'AFK Timeout:',
            value: `${afkTimeout_mins} mins`,
          }
        )
        .setFooter('we hope you have a great time! ')
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
    },
      permissions: [],
      requiredRoles: [],
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using
const allowed_channel_id = client.channels.cache.get("920766195878228028") instead.

Answer (score 0):

so after some more experimenting I made it work. all you need to do is:
after you define

```
 const allowed_channel_id = "920766195878228028"
```

you need to enter an if statement.

```
if (message.channel.id != allowed_channel_id) {}
```

in the if you basically ask if the id of the channel you're currently writing in equals to the id of your allowed channel.